# Is it possible to import Odoo15 Studio .zip file to Odoo16?

Tags: xml, import, odoo, odoo-16

I am currrently trying to import a .zip studio customizations file from my Odoo15 System and import it into my new Odoo16 System. I am getting one error after the other. For example:

```
Error while importing module 'studio_customization'.

 while parsing /tmp/tmplpxz_bpp/studio_customization/data/ir_model_fields.xml:61, somewhere inside
<record id="studio_customization.filename_for_x_studi_7150ce3c-5fb0-4142-a268-4e5ac2f0f774" model="ir.model.fields" context="{'studio': True}">
    <field name="complete_name" eval="False"/>
    <field name="compute" eval="False"/>
    <field name="copied" eval="True"/>
    <field name="depends" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>
    <field name="field_description">Customer order file</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6, 0, [])]"/>
    <field name="help" eval="False"/>
    <field name="index" eval="False"/>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
    <field name="name">x_studio_customer_order_file_filename</field>
    <field name="on_delete" eval="False"/>
    <field name="readonly" eval="False"/>
    <field name="related" eval="False"/>
    <field name="relation" eval="False"/>
    <field name="relation_field" eval="False"/>
    <field name="relation_table" eval="False"/>
    <field name="required" eval="False"/>
    <field name="selectable" eval="True"/>
    <field name="selection" eval="False"/>
    <field name="size" eval="False"/>
    <field name="state">manual</field>
    <field name="store" eval="True"/>
    <field name="tracking">1</field>
    <field name="translate" eval="False"/>
    <field name="ttype">char</field>
  </record> 
 Make sure those modules are installed and try again.
```

I have tried to comment out this record but then it shows me another one. I can not figure out what is wrong with this record ?

Yes the module is installed!

Are there changes from Odoo15 to Odoo16 which I have to consider here ?

Also I am getting the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj]
KeyError: ('ir.model.access', <function IrModelAccess._get_allowed_models at 0x7ff63046a3b0>, 2, 'write')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are able to do it yourself but the best way to migrate data between two version of odoo is to use the migration tools provided by Odoo [migration tools](https://upgrade.odoo.com/)

You are not dealing with a simple database where you can export content and import it in the new version here, you are dealing with more complex files produced by the studio module so it requires to be carefull.

Comment: And because he has used Odoo Studio, should mean he already has an enterprise subscription. So migrating the database by Odoo should already be possible.